# .htaccess - URLs amigáveis com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, regex, htaccess

Tenho a seguinte linha:

```
RewriteRule ^usuario\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,._-]+)?$ index.php?pg=usuarios&usuario=$1
```

Precisava que ele aceitasse os caracteres `@ : = ! ?`

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Que ele aceite onde? junto nos colchetes?

Comment: Em qualquer lugar se eu buscar J:osi=m@r@! não de erro

Comment: Sim nos colchetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possível Solução

```
RewriteRule ^usuario\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,._@:=!\?-]+)?$ index.php?pg=usuarios&usuario=$1
```

#### Notas

- `[]` funciona como uma captura por verificação, "no carácter que estou testando 'eu' aceito quais possibilidades?"
- Note que você só necessita uma vez o carácter para que ele seja aceito, desta forma o `,` não necessita aparecer varias vezes - embora eu creio que seu intuito era separar conteúdos
- Em regex não ha necessidade de separar conteúdo, ela segue simplesmente a sequencia passada `a-z,0-9,A-Z,` = `a-z0-9A-Z`
- Caracteres especiais podem ser pegos literalmente através do escape **`\`**, `\?`, `\+`
- Dentro do `[]` você tem dois meios de captura literalmente o `-` tendo em viste que ele também é um caractere especial (de, ate), mantendo ele no final `-]` ou aplicando escape `\-`

#### Melhoria

- Note que dento dos colchetes você tem `a-zA-Z0-9_` que é justamente o ancora `\w`

#### Solução melhorada

```
RewriteRule ^usuario\/([\w,.@:=!\?-]+)?$ index.php?pg=usuarios&usuario=$1
```